# Why does KendoUI grid add a row to the beginning of the grid and not give the User a choice using rowindex?

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

Im using KendoUi grids everywhere now and need some help ..

When my Kendo grid first loads I want the user to have the rows and an empty row at the BOTTOM not the top to indicate that they can add data . I dont want to use the in built "Add Row Button". 
I have the following

**Try1**

```
$(document).ready(function () 
{
    var grid = $("#grid").data("kendoGrid");
    grid.addRow();
    $(".k-grid-edit-row").appendTo("#grid tbody");  
}
```

This is supposed to move the row to the bottom of the grid , but it doesnt, it remans on top ?

**Try 2**
   I also tried to do something like

```
        var newRow = { field: "FirstName", Value: "" };
        var grid = $("#grid").data("kendoGrid");
        grid.dataSource.add(newRow);
```

This did not work either.

**Try 3**

But with this try , im not sure if there is a 'load' with the Kendoui Grid, i know there is a keydown , etc

```
 grid.tbody.on('load', function (e) 
 {               
    if ($(e.target).closest('tr').is(':last-child')) 
    {
        setTimeout(function () 
        {                      
            var totalrows = grid.dataSource.total();
            var data = grid.dataSource.data();
            var lastItem = data[data.length - 1];
            if (typeof lastItem !== 'undefined') 
            {
                if (lastItem.FirstName.trim() != "")
                   grid.addRow();

            }               
        })
    }
 }
```

any help would be great.

The full implementation details is below:

First i add the datasource, this is a simple implementation.

```
          var data = $scope.userdetails;
            var dataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({            
                transport: {
                    read: function (e) {
                        e.success(data);
                    },
                    update: function (e) {
                        e.success();
                    },
                    create: function (e) {
                        var item = e.data;
                        item.Id = data.length + 1;
                        e.success(item);
                    }
                },
                schema: {
                    model: {
                        id: "Id",
                        fields: {
                            FirstName: { type: "string" }
                        }
                    }
                }
            });
```

Then i define the grid

```
            let grid = $("#grid").kendoGrid({
                dataSource: dataSource,
                scrollable: false,
                navigatable: true,
                editable: {
                    createAt: "bottom"
                },
                dataBound: function (e) {
                    e.sender.tbody.find(".k-grid-Delete").each(function (idx, 
                    element) {
                        $(element).removeClass("k-button");
                    });
                },
                columns: [
                    {
                        field: "FirstName", title: "First Name"
                    },
                    {
                        command: [{ name: "Delete", text: "", click: $scope.delete, 
                   className: "far fa-trash-alt fa-fw" }],
                        title: " ",
                        width: "100px",
                        attributes: { class: "k-grid-column-text-centre" }
                    }
                ]

            }).data("kendoGrid");
```

I do the below process to add a blank row only when the user clicks tab on the last cell of the last row, but also want to add a blank when the page first loads with the grid.

```
            grid.tbody.on('keydown', function (e) {
                i`enter code here`f (e.keyCode == 9) {                
                    if ($(e.target).closest('tr').is(':last-child')) {
                        setTimeout(function () {                        
                            var totalrows = grid.dataSource.total();
                            var data = grid.dataSource.data();
                            var lastItem = data[data.length - 1];
                            if (typeof lastItem !== 'undefined') {
                                if (lastItem.FirstName.trim() == "")
                                    return;
                            }
                            grid.addRow();
                        })
                    }
                }
            });
```

This code still adds the row at the top of the grid not the bottom.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
       var newRow = { field: "FirstName", Value: "" };       
        grid.dataSource.add(newRow);
        grid.editRow($("#grid tr").last());
}
```

There is no other place that i add a row

Answer (score 0):

You try #2 is the right way to go. It probably added a row at the bottom, right? So you just need to programatically edit it:

```
var newRow = { field: "FirstName", Value: "" };
var grid = $("#grid").data("kendoGrid");
grid.dataSource.add(newRow);
grid.editRow($("#grid tr").last());
```

---

Demo:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8"/>
    <title>Kendo UI Snippet</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2020.2.513/styles/kendo.default-v2.min.css"/>

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2020.2.513/js/kendo.all.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  
<div id="grid"></div>
<script>
  let grid = $("#grid").kendoGrid({
    toolbar: ["save"],
    columns: [
      { field: "name" },
      { field: "age" }
    ],
    dataSource: {
     data: [
      { id: 1, name: "Jane Doe", age: 30 },
      { id: 2, name: "John Doe", age: 33 }
     ],
     schema:{
      model: {
       id: "id",
       fields: {
         age: { type: "number"}
       }
      }
     }
    },
    editable: true
  }).data('kendoGrid');
  
  grid.dataSource.add({});
 grid.editRow($("#grid tr").last());
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

[Dojo](https://dojo.telerik.com/AyOKoFaF)

If someone is using the built-in method, just use [`editable.createAt`](https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/grid/configuration/editable.createat) parameter.

Comment: I have tried , but still at the top it adds the row . I will add what i have to the original question

Comment: Details have been added to the original question.